# $nin issues with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Any idea why this query

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("4e2a4ca7f21a81331f0006c3"),
  "categories": {
    "$nin": [
      "Arts"
    ]
  }
}
```

returns the following record when we explicitly excluded "Arts" with $nin above?

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4e2a4ca7f21a81331f0006c3"),
   "categories": {
     "0": "Arts",
     "1": "Arts - Performance" 
  }
}
```

as a sanity check, I changed $nin to $in

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("4e2a4ca7f21a81331f0006c3"),
  "categories": {
    "$in": [
      "Arts"
    ]
  }
}
```

and it didn't return anything as expected.. but I'm still puzzled by the $nin result above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query is requesting a document with a specific ID and where the value for `categories` is not in a list of strings (in this case, `["Arts"]`). The value for `categories` for this document is an embedded document, `{ "0": "Arts", "1": "Arts - Performance" }`.

The second query returns nothing because that embedded document is not in the provided list of values for the `categories` field.

**Edit:** If you want to be able to search for categories using `$in` and `$nin`, you should consider converting the `categories` subdocument into an array:

```
> db.foo.save({categories: ["Arts", "Arts - Performance"]})                                                     
> db.foo.save({categories: ["Sports", "Sports - Baseball"]})
> db.foo.find({categories: {$nin: ["Arts"]}})                 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e2e3b49aed2871354b374eb"), "categories" : [ "Sports", "Sports - Baseball" ] }
> db.foo.find({categories: {$in: ["Arts"]}})                  
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e2e3b1eaed2871354b374ea"), "categories" : [ "Arts", "Arts - Performance" ] }
```

Comment: so, _id aside, what's the proper way of searching just for categories OTHER THAN "Arts" using the existing document structure?

Comment: thanks so much. oh, wow... I originally saved it as an associative array... which I now assume can't be searched through properly using $in/$nin ? hence, the reason you have asked me to convert it into a 1d array?

Comment: Sounds like you're using PHP? See the comment [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-104) for some cases where PHP arrays may be treated as objects rather than arrays, and how to avoid that.